# Deploy code to multiple production servers under the load balancer without continuous deployments

Tags: deployment, server, digital-ocean

I am the only developer (full-stack) in my company I have too much work other than automating the deployments as of now. In the future, we may hire a DevOps guy for the same.

Problem: We have 3 servers under Load Balancer. I don't want to block 2nd & 3rd servers till the 1st server updated and repeat the same with 2nd & 3rd because there might be huge traffic for one server initially and may fail at some specif time before other servers go live.

```
                                        Server 1


    User's ----> Load Balancer ---->    Server 2  -----> Database


                                        Server 3
```

***Personal Opinion***: Is there a way where we can pull the code by writing any scripts in the Load Balancer. I can replace the traditional Digital Ocean load balancer with Nginx Server making it a reverse proxy.

> NOTE: I know there are plenty of other questions asked in Stack
>   Overflow on the same but none of them solves my queries.

### Solutions I know

1. **GIT Hooks** - I know somewhat about GIT Hooks but don't want to use it because if I commit to master branch by mistake then it must not get sync to my production and create havoc in the live server and live users.
2. Open multiple tabs of servers and do it manually (Current Scenario). Believe me its pain in the ass :)

Any suggestions or redirects to the solutions will be really helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to write ansible playbook for this. With Ansible, you can specify to run it per one host at the time and also as the last step you can include verification check that checks if your application responds with response code 200 or it can query some endpoint that indicates the status of your application. If the check fails, Ansible will stop the execution. For example, in your case, Server1 deploys fine, but on server2 it fails. The playbook will stop and you will have servers 1 and 3 running.

I have done it myself. Works fine in environments without continuous deployments.
[Here is one example](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/dev-ops/automation/how-to-use-ansible-to-deploy-your-website/)